# C++ function as parameter error

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, function-parameter

I'm trying to run a function on each node traversed in a Binary Search Tree class I made. Here is the function that traverses the nodes of the BST and runs the function passed in as an argument on each node:

```
template<class ItemType, class OtherType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::Inorder(void visit(BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType>&), BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType>* node_ptr) const {
   if (node_ptr != nullptr) {
      Inorder(visit, node_ptr->GetLeftPtr());
      BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType> node = *node_ptr;
      visit(node);
      Inorder(visit, node_ptr->GetRightPtr());
   }  // end if
}  // end inorder
```

This is a private member function of the BST class, so it gets called by a public member function:

```
template<class ItemType, class OtherType>
void BinarySearchTree<ItemType, OtherType>::InorderTraverse(void visit(BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType>&)) const
{
   Inorder(visit, root_);
}  // end inorderTraverse
```

In my main file, I created this function to pass in as the argument:

```
void displayItem(BinaryNode<string, LinkedQueue<int> >& anItem)
```

The traversal is called like this:

```
tree1Ptr->InorderTraverse(displayItem);
```

When I compile, I get this error, and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
MainBST.cpp:62:29: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void
      (*)(BinaryNode<std::__1::basic_string<char>, LinkedQueue<int> > &)' with
      an lvalue of type 'void (string &)' (aka 'void (basic_string<char,
      char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > &)'): type mismatch at 1st parameter
      ('BinaryNode<std::__1::basic_string<char>, LinkedQueue<int> > &' vs
      'string &' (aka 'basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >
      &'))
  tree1Ptr->InorderTraverse(displayItem);
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~
./BinarySearchTree.h:42:29: note: passing argument to parameter 'visit' here
  void InorderTraverse(void visit(BinaryNode<ItemType, OtherType>&)) const;
```

If anyone understands the error and can decipher it and help me, I will be very grateful. If you need me to drop more code, I'll be glad to do it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Got another `displayItem` out there? Compiler's pretty sure `displayItem` takes a `string`, not a `BinaryNode`. A stale forward declaration, perhaps?

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much. Wow, I've been staring at this project for over 8 hours that I had forgotten about the declaration. It was just that, I updated the definition, but not the declaration. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void
>         (*)(BinaryNode, LinkedQueue > &)' with
>         an lvalue of type 'void (string &)' (aka 'void (basic_string, allocator > &)'): type mismatch at 1st parameter
>         ('BinaryNode, LinkedQueue > &' vs
>         'string &' (aka 'basic_string, allocator >
>         &'))

Break it down!

> cannot initialize a parameter of type

A function has been called with a parameter of the wrong type.

> 'void (*)(BinaryNode, LinkedQueue > &)'

Expected type

> with an lvalue of type 'void (string &)'

Provided type

English translation: Function was called with `void displayItem(std::string &)`, not `void displayItem(BinaryNode<string, LinkedQueue<int> >& anItem)`.

Solution: Ensure `void displayItem(BinaryNode<string, LinkedQueue<int> >& anItem)` is declared ahead of first use. Possibly search for and remove or rename `void displayItem(std::string &)` to prevent future confusion.